# Using file.write() in python

Tags: python

I just had a quick question that keeps breaking my program. For some reason file.write() will only take in 1 string or variable and my question is there any way around this?

For example Im asking if it is possible to write multiple variables or strings to a file at once. Like this but without .write() because it doesn't allow you to.

```
file.write("apples: ", numApples, "\n oranges: ", numOranges)
```

Any help or suggestions are welcome!

The best answer I thought of right now is to make it all a string then send it to the file.

Comment: `file.write("apples: " + str(numApples) + "\n oranges: " + str(numOranges))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert all the arguments to string and append them together.

For example,  `str(var)`  will convert  `var`  to string type.

You can simply use  `str(numApples)`  and so on in your case and append them using  `+`  (string concatenate) operator.
The modified code will look like

`file.write("apples: " + str(numApples) + "\n oranges: " + str(numOranges))`

Here you have just one string argument instead of 4.

Comment: Its the same thing I just showed DOOM I would have to do it before the .write then send the new string there but I was wondering if there was an easier way.... Nevermind Im an idiot

Comment: Yeah I still had the "," in there instead of the "+". Like I said stupid mistake

Answer (score 2):

you could also use format - :

```
file.write("apples: {0}\n oranges: {1}".format(numApples, numOranges) )
```

This gives you the flexibility to add formatting to the numbers, which you don't have with the the simple string concatenation solution.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Im still new to python so Im a little confused.

Comment: For example, you can do things like `file.write("apples:{0:5d}\noranges:{1:4d}".format(numApples, numOranges))` to line the numbers up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file.writelines`, which takes an iterable of strings, rather than a single string.

Or else use `print(*args, file=)` which takes anything and calls str() for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make one arguemnt from your strings, there are few ways to do that:

1. make each part a string using str(), then concatenate using a '+'
2. Using str.format
3. Using nice and concise old syntax:

   ```
   file.write("apples: %s\noranges:%s" % (numApples, numOranges))
   ```